# Webservice in Java using CXF api in netbeans

Tags: java, apache, web-services, netbeans

I want to create a web service using CXF api. As I am not great with web applications, could someone provide me with a very basic tutorial for beginners to implement web services using CXF api in netbeans ? The user's guide at the apache CXF website are not helping at all.

Comment: why are they not helping at all ?

Comment: probably because they assume some info that users already should know, and I am missing that

Comment: can you show what you have tried base on the tutorials ? and what you don't understand exactly